# mysql error (should be simple for an average scholar :)

Tags: mysql

I'll be very straightforward and just paste MySql query I am executing and error code I am getting. This should be easy to solve for ones who know :)

```
CREATE TABLE formular(

ime VARCHAR( 30 ) ,
prezime VARCHAR( 30 ) ,
godine TINYINT,
pol VARCHAR( 10 ) ,
adresa VARCHAR( 45 ) ,
drzava VARCHAR( 45 ) ,
tel_kucni VARCHAR( 30 ) ,
tel_mobilni VARCHAR( 30 ) ,
e_posta VARCHAR( 45 ) ,
dat_rodjenja DATE,
zanimanje VARCHAR( 90 ) ,
prevoz BOOL,
poznanstvo BOOL,
pozn_imena_priroda VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
mat_jezik VARCHAR( 60 ) ,
str_jezik VARCHAR( 60 ) ,
stari_novi_student ENUM(  "stari",  "novi" ) ,
ranije_meditacije BOOL,
ran_med_detalji VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
poducavanje BOOL,
pod_detalji VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
izvor_informacije VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
prvi_kurs_datum VARCHAR( 35 ) ,
prvi_kurs_mesto VARCHAR( 60 ) ,
prvi_kurs_ucitelj VARCHAR( 60 ) ,
posl_kurs_datum VARCHAR( 35 ) ,
posl_kurs_mesto VARCHAR( 60 ) ,
posl_kurs_ucitelj VARCHAR( 60 ) ,
ukupno_kurseva TINYINT,
br_ceo_sedenja TINYINT,
br_ceo_sluzenih TINYINT,
ostali_kurs_sedenje VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
ostali_kurs_sluzenje VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
tehnike_pos_kursa BOOL,
teh_pos_kursa_detalji VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
poducavanje_drug_tehn VARCHAR BOOL,
pod_dr_teh_detalji VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
svakodnevna_praksa BOOL,
svak_prak_detalji VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
pripreme_mesta BOOL,
datum_dolaska VARCHAR( 60 ) ,
datum_odlaska VARCHAR( 60 ) ,
zdravlje_problem BOOL,
zdrav_prob_detalji VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
trudnoca BOOL,
ment_zdravlje_prob BOOL,
men_zdrav_detalji VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
droge BOOL,
droge_detalji VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
lekovi BOOL,
lekovi_detalji VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
ostalo VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
datum_prijave DATE
)

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bool,
pod_dr_teh_detalji varchar(255),
svakodnevna_praksa bool,
svak_prak_det' at line 44
```

Very much thank you :)

Comment: What is 'poducavanje_drug_tehn VARCHAR BOOL,' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line is wrong:

```
poducavanje_drug_tehn VARCHAR BOOL,
```

you have to change it to varchar OR bool

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have given the data type of `poducavanje_drug_tehn` as `VARCHAR BOOL`. 
 The datatype can either be `VARCHAR` or `BOOL`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

`poducavanje_drug_tehn VARCHAR BOOL`

You'll want to choose either `VARCHAR` (and set a length for it) or `BOOL`, not both. The error message will point you to the text *right after* the error itself.

Answer (score 1):

This column:

```
poducavanje_drug_tehn VARCHAR BOOL,
```

should be a VARCHAR or a BOOL, not both